# Bootstrap 5 changing the text on a collapse button when clicked

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I have looked everywhere for this solution and have found what to do for bootstrap 3 and 4 but not version 5.

I have the following code:

```
<div class="p-3">9 Members Online
  <a class="p-1 btn btn-info" data-bs-toggle="collapse" id="toggle" href="#hiddenContent" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">Show</a>
</div>

<div class="collapse" id="hiddenContent">
  <div class="card card-body bg-transparent">
    Member 1. <br><br> Member 2.<br><br> Member 3.<br><br> Member 4.<br><br> Member 5.<br><br> Member 6.<br><br> Member 7.<br><br> Member 8.<br><br> Member 9.<br><br>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want the text "Show" to read "Hide" when clicked.

Comment: What have you tried so far to accomplish this?

Comment: That's the problem, I haven't found anything so far to try, at present I am using a checkbox with javascript but I wanted to convert the page to Bootstrap 5.

Comment: Please read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). SO isn't a code writing or solution finding service. It's expected that you first show an effort to solve the problem for yourself. You said "have found what to do for bootstrap 3 and 4" .. so where is that code? how is it not working for Bootstrap 5?

Comment: Your title states that Bootstrap 5 is taking a certain action. Is that what you intended, or is that a mashup of words attempting to tag your post with Bootstrap 5?

Comment: JavaScript that works for on version of Bootstrap will work for another. The answer below is universally applicable. Zim's point was well made.

Comment: From what I have researched, under Bootstrap 4 the scripts I saw here worked but I wanted to use Bootstrap 5 for my code and the scripts didn't work with 5's code

I tried changing data-toggle="collapse" to data-bs-toggle="collapse" and many other things, which led me to coming here to post my first ever question here, expecting the answer to relate to BS5.

Geeeeeeeeeze! Do you guys always come down so hard on newbies? I'm a pensioner trying to learn to code during the pandemic, you haven't exactly encouraged me to come back! But I am very grateful to Rüzgar for the help he gave me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want to achieve? Just click on "Run Code Snippet" button and see if this works.

```js
function toggleText() {
  var x = document.getElementById("toggle");
  if (x.innerHTML === "Show") {
    x.innerHTML = "Hide";
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = "Show";
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<a onclick="toggleText()" class="p-1 btn btn-info" data-bs-toggle="collapse" id="toggle" href="#hiddenContent" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">Show</a>

           <div class="collapse" id="hiddenContent">
               <div class="card card-body bg-transparent">
                       Member 1. <br><br>
                   Member 2.<br><br>
                   Member 3.<br><br>
                   Member 4.<br><br>
                   Member 5.<br><br>
                   Member 6.<br><br>
                   Member 7.<br><br>
                   Member 8.<br><br>
                   Member 9.<br><br>
               </div>
           </div>
```